# How to create Kubernetes cluster on EKS with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm trying to create K8s cluster on Amazon EKS with Terraform. All the code is on github: https://github.com/amorfis/aws-eks-terraform

access_key and secret are configured for the user which has the necessary policy, as seen in README.md.

I run `terraform init`, then `terraform apply` and it fails with following error: 
`module.eks.null_resource.update_config_map_aws_auth (local-exec): error: unable to recognize "aws_auth_configmap.yaml": Unauthorized`

I also checked in the modules, and it looks like it should create 2 files: `aws_auth_configmap.yaml` and `kube_config.yaml`, but instead I can see 2 different files created: `kubeconfig_eks-cluster-created-with-tf` and `config-map-aws-auth_eks-cluster-created-with-tf.yaml`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here seems to be that you try to use an AssumedRole but then the module attempts to do local exec which is why it fails.

What you would be required is something like this where you add 
 "kubeconfig_aws_authenticator_env_variables" to the module taken from the official example like below -

```
module "my-cluster" {
  source       = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  cluster_name = "my-cluster"
  kubeconfig_aws_authenticator_env_variables = {
             AWS_PROFILE = "NameOfProfile"
  }
  subnets      = ["subnet-abcde012", "subnet-bcde012a", "subnet-fghi345a"]
  vpc_id       = "vpc-1234556abcdef"

  worker_groups = [
    {
      instance_type = "m4.large"
      asg_max_size  = 5
    }
  ]

  tags = {
    environment = "test"
  }
}
```

Note:  The following is added -

```
 kubeconfig_aws_authenticator_env_variables = {
    AWS_PROFILE = "NameOfProfile"
  }
```

Replace the value of profile  with whatever name you have provided with in the ~/.aws/config.